# Rollback Operation not happening with @Transactional from Abstract Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions

```
    **Sample Code Snippet and use case**
```

**Here I am extending abstract class and in abstract class only i have final method which has been marked with @Transactional, so upon any exception in any of the 3 methods implemented the transaction should rollback but its not happening.**

```
    public abstract class A<E e>{
         public abstract void processData(String str);//process some data
         public abstract E persistData(E e);//save some data based on E object
         public abstract E sendData(E e);
            
   @Transactional(readOnly=false,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,rollbackfor={all custom exception classes}
        public final E processMethod(E e){
        E e1;
        processData(String str);
        try{
        e1= persistData(e);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException();//or custom Exception
        }
    try{
        e1= sendData(e1);**//Some Exception happens here but still data saved by persistData().**
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException();//or custom Exception
        }
         
    
               }
        
        public class C extends A<Entity>{
        @override
        public void processData(){ //processing Data 
    }
          @override
        public Entity persistData(Entity e){
        //saving data successfully
        }
        @override
        public Entity sendData(Entity e){
        //any Exception in sendData Method after persisting Data in Db is not rolling back, instead saving data in db upon exception also
        }
        }
    
    **Sample Code only to follow use case** 
        @SpringBootApplication
        @EnableTransactionManagement
        public class Application{
        C c= new C();
        E e=new E();
        e=c.processMethod(e);
        }
```

Comment: Are you really instantiating your class with  `C c= new C();`? If so, your `@Transactional` annotation will not work. You have to let Spring create your bean for you, so it can wrap `processMethod` in a Proxy with Transaction logic.

Comment: No i am Autowiring it only, its only to give a glimpse of code.

Comment: It started Working when i am using Interface instead of Abstract Class. Thanks!!